# Android java 'Else if' just doing one line of code instead of all the block

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am working a code which simply parses an XML; however, in a simple if-else if structure the app only does the inmediate statement after I open the {

```
private void processParsingUsuario(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String eltName = null;
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("Info","inicia el xml");
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            eltName = parser.getName();
            Log.i("Info","inicia el tag " + eltName);
            if("usu_id".equals(eltName)) {
                Log.i("Info","usu id = " + parser.nextText());
                usuario.usu_id = parser.nextText();
            } else if("usu_nombre".equals(eltName)) {
                Log.i("Info","usu nombre = " + parser.nextText());
            } else if("usu_nombrecorto".equals(eltName)) {
                welcomeText.setText("Hola " + parser.nextText()); 
                Log.i("Info","usu nombre = " + parser.nextText());
            }
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }
}
```

In the case of the last 'else if' it should be doing both the setText and the Log, however, it is just doing the setText.
If I switch them (if I place the log first, and then the setText, it just does the Log.

Comment: You are sure that `parser.nextText()` does not throw an exception at this point of time? -- You might want to assign `parser.nextText()` to a variable if it is supposed to have the same value for both statements.

Comment: Thank you @second That worked! (As you can see, I'm kind of a newbie both in Android as here in stackflow)